# What is the ALSA timer interface used for?

Tags: linux, timer, alsa

I have a hard time to figure out what the ALSA timer interface is actually useful for.

The [documentation](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/timer.html) is quite lean:

> Timer interface is designed to use internal timers in sound hardware, but it can be driven with any timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the <strike>good</strike> old times of MS-DOS and 16-bit Windows, there was no good API to run the system timer at a high frequency. So some sound chipsets implemented a separate hardware timer so that multimedia applications did have the ability to use such a timer.

The ALSA API has a timer interface to allow this part of the hardware to be used.

Nowadays, this interface is no longer useful.

Comment: "Nowadays, this interface is no longer useful."

Comment: Nowadays, this timer is indispensable if you need a precise clock for MIDI, among other things...

Answer (score 1):

"Nowadays, this interface is no longer useful." 
I am not sure how valid this statement is. I trying to use the dshare plugin for creating a TDM audio frame with 16 channels and this timer is driving me crazy as you cannot use the plugins without it. infact all plugins use the timer. Atleast Dshare/Dmix/Dsnoop plugins use the timer. 
The timer seems like it sets up a counter (unsigned int) at the start of the playback tracks the frames in time. essentially, its a running counter that any playback will sync up with and the difference between the application counter and the Timer (counter) will give you the #of samples that still need to be played.